# Passing a List To multi value Converter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress

I have DataGrid Column Like this

```
<dxg:GridControl DockPanel.Dock="Right" Name="gridControl" ItemsSource="{Binding FilterWiseListOfWorkOrder,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" >

        <dxg:GridColumn Header="Name" >
                            <dxg:GridColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CellBackRoundColorOtTypeConvertor}" >
                                    <Binding Path="RowData.Row" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" />
                                    <Binding Path="Listofcolor" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </dxg:GridColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                        </dxg:GridColumn>
     </dxg:GridControl>
```

Here  `<Binding Path="RowData.Row" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" />` Row data is passed to convertor

But `<Binding Path="Listofcolor" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" />` Not able to pass the Listofcolor. this is not in the itemsource of `Datagrid`. `Listofcolor` is in Vm as a seperate list

**Convertor**

```
public class CellBackRoundColorOtTypeConvertor : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {if (values[0] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue || values[1] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
             // Here values[1] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue is true
            //Some Conversions
        }
    }
```

**VM**

```
 public List<Ots> FilterWiseListOfWorkOrder
            {
                get { return filterWiseListOfWorkOrder; }
                set
                {
                    filterWiseListOfWorkOrder = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FilterWiseListOfWorkOrder"));
                }
            }


// This will fill in Ctor of Vm 
     public List<string> Listofcolor
            {
                get { return listofcolor; }
                set { listofcolor = value; }
            }
```

Q: How can pass this Listofcolor to converter?

Tried `DataContext.Listofcolor` and tried using ElementName too

Update on Comment

[image: SS]

Comment: You will need Datacontext dot something with a relativesource binding because otherwise it is looking for a property of the control. I'm surprised your first binding is working. Maybe Rowdata is a dp on your usercontrol though. I can only guess because you haven't given us enough code . Don't make us guess.

Comment: @Andy I tried using `DataContext.Listofcolor`

Comment: @Andy Check now Placed all the required things

Comment: Listofcolor isn't a dependency property. Put a break point in your converter and see what you're actually getting in values[1] when you use DataContext.Listofcolor as the path.  Maybe you're getting the right stuff but your code isn't handling it properly.

Comment: @Andy No use I added the ss

Comment: Is RowData a property inside FilterWiseListOfWorkOrder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Binding Path="View.DataContext.Listofcolor"/>`
 This is what im missing  [link](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T265328/multibinding-giving-a-dependencyproperty-unsetvalue-for-one-of-the-values-in-the-converter)

Answer (score 0):

Access Listofcolor via DataContext if your VM is datacontext of this usercontrol.

```
 <Binding Path="DataContext.Listofcolor" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" />
```

Comment: `tried it DataContext.Listofcolor and tried using ElementName too` in question I mentioned that

Comment: what is your main control for which Viewmodel is set,is it a window or usercontrol?

Comment: `usercontrol` It self

Comment: Please check it now